# How can I customize Spotlight so that if a number (or some pattern matching a regex) is typed, I can execute a command or script?

Tags: macos, spotlight, script

I want to "augment" Spotlight to do things like:

- If an integer (`^\d+$`), open a site, `example.com/$0`.
- If a UUID (`^\d{8}-\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{12}$`), open another site.
- If a string beginning with "user:" (`^user:(.*)`), open another site.

And so on.

What utilities or scripts can I put together to achieve this. (Can Hammerspoon be integrated?) I'm willing to use any tool (even paid, as long as it's widely supported), and also willing to do some scripting or programming.

Comment: One hack would be to assign an AppleScript to a shortcut key that you can press from within Spotlight and have the script analyse what you’ve input into the search box and perform those tasks for you.  Another, better way is to Dow load [**Alfred**](https://alfredapp.com) and pay for their power pack, then you can achieve a lot from, what is essentially Spotlight on steroids.  _Launchbar_ is another alternative that I haven’t used.  Plus there are others that are open source on GitHub (these types of softwares are called _”Application Launchers”_).